# Get all Ethereum accounts from Metamask

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask

I want to get all the accounts that a user has added in Metamask. I tried all web3.js methods to get accounts, but I always get just one account which is always the currently selected one.

According to web3.js documentation, `web3.eth.getAccounts()` should return all accounts that this node controls. However, I am getting an array with just the currently selected one. Needless to say, I have multiple accounts created in Metamask.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says: [Account List Reflects User Preference](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#raising_hand-account-list-reflects-user-preference)

> When a user selects an account in MetaMask, that account silently becomes the `web3.eth.accounts[0]` in your JS context, the only member of the `web3.eth.accounts` array.

It depends from web3 provider MetaMask uses by default, I guess. Checkout [Why does web3.eth.getAccounts() return only 1 account?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41283/why-does-web3-eth-getaccounts-return-only-1-account) question to see that some providers returns more than one account, and it depends from configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call MetaMask's `getAccounts()`, it prompts users to select a list of accounts to connect. The user can select none (reject), one, or many. Only the user can control that, not the developer implementing the request due to security and privacy considerations.

Note, that the API changed and `window.web3` is no longer available. You will have to use the `window.ethereum` object now:

```js
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
  // connects to MetaMask
  const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
} else {
  // tell the user to install an `ethereum` provider extension
}
```